# How to exclude Kotlin from OkHttp?

Tags: java, kotlin, netbeans, ant, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp version 4.12.0. I have the `.jar` included in the `Libraries` folder in Netbeans.

I attempt to make a simple post request, but get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker
```

I'm not using Kotlin. And do no wish to install, or use it.

Is it possible to exclude the Kotlin classes? I use `okio-jvm` which doesn't include the Kotlin classes, but `okhttp` doesn't appear to have a Java only package.

I'm using Ant.

Thanks

Comment: You're not using Kotlin, but OkHttp is. The [OkHttp Requirements](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#requirements) section says that OkHttp depends on the Kotlin Standard Library. Just include it - don't worry, it's only a dependency, you're not "installing" Kotlin.

Comment: Also, you're not supposed to use `okio-jvm` - that's an internal implementation library used by `okio`. As the documentation says, you should use `okio`. On the other hand, `okhttp` as you say "doesn't appear to have a JVM only package" because okhttp is _only_ for the JVM platform. (And the Kotlin library that it uses is a JVM library.)

Comment: Upvoted because it's a valid question, even though the answer is "Don't worry about it" :-)

Comment: @k314159 I understand this. It is required to install `okio` when using `okhttp`, as you know. But I intended to seek out the non-Kotlin versions. The reason I mentioned it in the question is because a java only `okio` exists. I found `okio-jvm`, and assumed there may be a `okhttp-jvm`, but there wasn't.

Comment: @k314159 afaik netbeans has no support for Kotlin. How would I include the Kotlin standard library?

Comment: Kotlin is a language that compiles to Java Bytecode. In that respect, the only difference between Kotlin and Java is the source code syntax. There is no need for Netbeans to support Kotlin. The Kotlin Standard Library _is_ a JVM library, and you can include it in your dependencies in the same way as you would include any other dependency.

Comment: Btw the dependency you need to include is https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.22